# Retrieving Data deep from Firebase Query (iOS, Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have been developing my Job board application for a while now. I'm a total newbie to programming and swift. I wanted to allow my users to post jobs and view them and also apply for the jobs via the app. Similar to 'Freelancer' app. I am using Firebase for my database and the issue I have now is:

This is my Database Query :

```
"Users": {
    "UserID" : {
        "Region" : {
            "autoID : {
                "Job Title" : String
                "Job Description" : String
                "Company Name" : String 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I have to retrieve data from job details which is under autoID and UserID which always show an error - Cannot use multiple queryOrderedBy calls!

This is my retrieve function

```
func retrievePost() {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let postDB = ref.child("Users")

    postDB.queryOrdered(byChild: "Region").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
        let jobTitle = snapshotValue["Job Title"]!
        let companyName = snapshotValue["Company Name"]!
        let jobDesc = snapshotValue["Job Description"]!

        let posted = post()
        posted.jobTitle = jobTitle
        posted.company = companyName
        posted.jobDescription = jobDesc

        self.jobsPosted.append(posted)

        self.feedTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The user should be able to post a job and other users should be able to view the jobs posted and also later edit and update it. Considering all these, What will be the solution ?

Will these be possible in firebase ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The `.queryOrderedByKey()` seems meaningless in the code you shared. If you remove that, and the code compiles, what is wrong with the result?

Comment: I used it to access the childByAutoId() I created under region

Comment: This won't work as your data is too deep and the query isn't structured correctly. The query is looking for child nodes of Region that contain a value. However, you've not specified which child node or what it should contain. The larger issue is that the child nodes of Region are a bunch of childByAutoId's which obviously will not match anything specific you're looking for. On that note, the question is pretty vague as to what you are actually trying to do. Are you looking for a specific job, or all jobs or all jobs within a specific company? update your question and we'll take a look!